# How to find minimum in multiple records with same key in java?

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures

I have collected some records from file and want to perform group by and minimum on the records similar to SQL. Records is in the form of key value pairs where value is **not a float or double value** like:
here values are version numbers like every software has version numbers based on releases like : 10.1.1 , 10.1.2, 10.1.3 etc

```
 A 1.12
 A 1.13
 A 1.45
 B 5.6
 B 4.5
 C 5.6.4

 Output should be ->  A 1.12
                      B 4.5
                      C 5.6.4
```

Initially I started to solve this problem by using a `HashMap` data structure:

```
Map<String,List<String>> map = new HashMap<>();
```

As values are not float or double I iterate through all values and removed decimal point and concatenated digits to form integer.

Eg :  A 112  A 113

I got stuck at point , how to find key which has minimum value ? I tried to use TreeMap but no luck.

Can anyone help me how to find key which has minimum value ?

output should be : A 1.12  B 4.5  C 5.6.4

for single record like Eg : C 5.6.4 , minimum is single record.

Based on my data structure selection, `Map<String,List<Integer>>`, I am stuck is how to find key which has minimum value, like we do in SQL queries, using group by and min aggregate function. , here i got A -> [] A -> [] A -> [] B -> [] B -> [] C -> [] ** Here challenge is finding minimum among multiple list for same key ** , as you can see based on my data structure selection same key has multiple lists.

Comment: `5.6.4` what is this value? `TreeMap` sorted based on key, not on values.

Comment: Start by creating two separate functions: one to group, one to order (within a group). Then it's simply a matter of grouping the items, ordering the groups (and hence obtaining the minimum values), and selecting the minimum value from each group. But this is a different question, once the two prerequisite functions are written ..

Comment: Can you please elaborate more on what the task is about. I am not able to understand how you are saying output should be  A 1.12 B 4.5 C 5.6.4

Comment: values are version numbers like android has version numbers 4.3.1 , 3.2.1 etc.

Comment: I have used Map<String,List<Integer>> map = new HashMap<>() data structure.

Comment: @deepak Discussing data structures is meaningless without first having the two functions outlined above. The two functions - one to group, one to establish an ordering - are a requirement of *any* solution. The data structures which come later merely help *with* the grouping or the ordering. (And there are questions that already cover both tasks.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please Find the below solution :

You can maintain a HashMap with "key" as String and "value" as [PriorityQueue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html).

```
HashMap<String,PriorityQueue<String>> map = new HashMap<String,PriorityQueue<String>>();
```

You can group the values by the Key and can maintain the values in the PriorityQueue.

Java 
's [PriorityQueue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html) is a Min Heap with the smallest value stored at the root. 
when you invoke the peek() method on the priorityQueue it will return the min value stored at the root.

Below is the sample code which will help you :

```
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.PriorityQueue;
public class GroupAndFindMinimum {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        HashMap<String,PriorityQueue<String>> map = new HashMap<String,PriorityQueue<String>>();

        PriorityQueue<String> q1 = new PriorityQueue<String>();
        q1.add("1.12");q1.add("1.13");q1.add("1.45");

        PriorityQueue<String> q2 = new PriorityQueue<String>();
        q2.add("5.6");q2.add("4.5");

        PriorityQueue<String> q3 = new PriorityQueue<String>();
        q3.add("5.6.4");

        map.put("A",q1);
        map.put("B", q2);
        map.put("C", q3);


        for(Iterator<? extends Map.Entry<? extends String, ? extends PriorityQueue<String>>> it = map.entrySet().iterator(); it.hasNext() ;)
        {
            Map.Entry<? extends String, ? extends PriorityQueue<String>> t = it.next();
            System.out.println(t.getKey() + " " + t.getValue().peek());
        }

    }

}
```

Below is the Output of above program :

```
A 1.12
B 4.5
C 5.6.4
```

If you need the **MAX value to be returned for each group** then you can achieve it with the help of an "**Comparator**" as well.

Below is the code for that :

```
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.PriorityQueue;
public class GroupAndFindMinimum {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        HashMap<String,PriorityQueue<String>> map = new HashMap<String,PriorityQueue<String>>();
        comparatorPQ comp = new comparatorPQ<String>();

        PriorityQueue<String> q1 = new PriorityQueue<String>(3,comp);
        q1.add("1.12");q1.add("1.13");q1.add("1.45");

        PriorityQueue<String> q2 = new PriorityQueue<String>(2,comp);
        q2.add("5.6");q2.add("4.5");

        PriorityQueue<String> q3 = new PriorityQueue<String>(1,comp);
        q3.add("5.6.4");

        map.put("A",q1);
        map.put("B", q2);
        map.put("C", q3);


        for(Iterator<? extends Map.Entry<? extends String, ? extends PriorityQueue<String>>> it = map.entrySet().iterator(); it.hasNext() ;)
        {
            Map.Entry<? extends String, ? extends PriorityQueue<String>> t = it.next();
            System.out.println(t.getKey() + " " + t.getValue().peek());
        }

    }

}

class comparatorPQ<k> implements Comparator
{

    @Override
    public int compare(Object a1, Object b1) {
        String a = null ,b= null;

        if(a1 instanceof String)
         a = (String)a1;

        if(b1 instanceof String)
        b = (String)b1;


        if( b.compareTo(a) > 1 )
            return 1;
        else if(b.compareTo(a) < 1)
            return -1;
        return 0;
    }

}
```

Output :

```
A 1.45
B 5.6
C 5.6.4
```

Comment: PriorityQueue data structure selection for value seems right option for this requirement.

Answer (score 1):

The first challenge would be to find the "minimal" value. Simply removing the periods and treating the values as integers is insufficient - that would result in `6.5.4.` being "smaller" than `1.2.3.4.`, which doesn't seem to be what you intended. A better approach would be to split the strings by the period and treat each element individually as an `int`:

```
public String min(String v1, String v2) {
    // Any string should be "smaller" than null
    if (v1 == null) {
        return v2;
    }
    if (v2 == null) {
        return v1;
    }

    // Split both of them and iterate the common indexes:
    String[] v1parts = v1.split("\\.");
    String[] v2parts = v2.split("\\.");
    int commonLenth = Math.min(v1parts.length, v2parts.length);
    for (int i = 0; i < commonLength; ++i) {
        int v1elem = Integer.parseInt(v1parts[i]);
        int v2elem = Integer.parseInt(v2parts[i]); 
        if (v1elem < v2elem) {
            return v1;
        } else if (v1elem > v2elem) {
            return v2;
        }
    }

    // Done iterating the common indexes and they are all equal
    // The shorter string is therefore the minimal one:
    if (v1parts.length < v2parts.length) {
        return v1;
    } 
    return v2;
}
```

Now that you have such a function, it's just a matter of iterating the key-value pairs and placing the minimal value in a `Map`. E.g. (pseudo-code assuming you have some sort of `Pair` class):

```
Map<String, String> minimums = new HashMap<>();
for (Pair<String, String> entry : myListOfPairs) {
      String key = entry.getKey();
      minimums.put(key, min(entry.getValue(), minimums.get(key));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

An O(n) algorithm that parses the input once and keeps on updating the output map should suffice. I am assuming that the input is provided in the form of two lists with equal size.

```
public Map<String, String> groupAndFindMinimum(ArrayList< String > inputKeys, ArrayList< String > inputValues){
    Map<String, String> output = new ArrayMap<String, String>();
    int i = 0;
    for(String key : inputKeys){
        if(output.containsKey(key)){
            output[key] = min(output[key], inputValues.get(i));
        }
        else{
            output.insert(key, inputValues.get(i));
        }
        i++;
    }
    return output;
}
```

I hope this helps.
Your algorithm to find minimum is correct.